# Why do I get a 401 error when I send a token beyond its expiration date?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I used jwt in my project and I have a series of methods that are general, but for some reason, I need to send the token in the header of the requester. When the token is sent, if its expiration date is over, it gives error 401 and does not enter the method at all.

The method does not have an Authorize filter, and this issue, while there is no Route at all, returns 401 if there is a token in the header.

Before it reaches the Routing middleware, the jwt OnAuthenticationFailed event catches it The order of the middleware is also observed Net core project 3.1

[image: postman]

[image: my method]

Comment: Not clear about your requirement.Did you mean it returns 401 although you add `AllowAnonymous` attribute?If so,I think you need to provide more code about how do you generate the jwt and how did you configure your Startup.cs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use claim to regenerate the token using jwt.

What is the frontend script are you using? jQuery or angular ?
If it's jQuery you need to use jQuery ajaxprefilter. 
Which will execute before the actual call made to server side.

So if token expires, which will checked in ajaxprefilter.

If expires, Call claim on aap.net core middleware side and the re-generated the token. Then the original call will be made.

Comment: this is not the problem. The main problem is that it also authenticates methods that have AllowAnonymous attributes